# Customizing Razor view engine

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am creating a simple CMS and I want the users of the system to easily code the views. For example instead of writing:

```
@ViewBag.some_data_from_cms
```

I want them to write something like this:

```
{{some_data_from_cms}}
```

and you can guess the rest.

Is is possible with Razor or do I have to invent (or inherit from Razor) a new engine?

Comment: I don't think that it's possible with Razor.